# Elasticsearch transform document before indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, transformation

I am trying to transform some elasticsearch documents before indexing them into my index using a custom filter. My intention is to replace a string pattern by another string before indexing the document (in this case it is 'a' by 'u'). Here is the index definition:

```
PUT index_8
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0,
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "char_filter": {
                    "my_pattern": {
                        "type": "pattern_replace",
                        "pattern": "a",
                        "replacement": "u"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "my_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                         "char_filter": [
                            "my_pattern"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "test": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I insert a document like this and then I try to retrieve it I get:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/index_8/my_type/1' -d '{ "test" : "aaaa" }'
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index_8/my_type/1?pretty=true'

{
  "_index" : "index_8",
  "_type" : "my_type",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 4,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "test" : "aaaa"
  }
}
```

As you can see the "test" field is intact while you should see "uuuu"...

Maybe I'm not understanding well how the filters are working or maybe it is not possible to do this before indexing, but for querying.

Comment: What you're seeing is the source of the document and that won't change, however, the tokens that have been indexed have been affected by your analyzer. Try searching for `aaaa` and `uuuu`, what do you get?

Comment: I missed the following code (I'm not able to edit my question!):
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index_8/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty=true' -d 'aaa'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "uuu",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}

Comment: Indeed, querying operation works fine, but I would like to be able to transform the data before indexing. So it is not possible to alter the source using a filter?

Comment: @cabreracanal it is not possible to alter the source through filter, do you have to use another application to change that before pushing to elasticsearch, if you are using logstash you can use mutate option.

Comment: It is going to be possible in ES 5 with [ingest nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html). Now you can either modify your indexing logic to do the transformation or use Logstash to do it for you.

Comment: Ok. Roger that. Thank you all.